Linear mixed model, negative information criteria values and Hessian matrix not positive definite?
I'm trying to perform this operation in R.
glmm_res <- glmer(Chla ~ Temp + Sal + TP + Pluviometry + 
              (1 | season) + (1 | river), data = Chla_model, 
              family = poisson)
summary(glmm_res)

I get the following messages:
Notification messages:
1: In vcov.merMod(object, use.hessian = use.hessian) :
  variance-covariance matrix computed from finite-difference Hessian is
not positive definite or contains NA values: falling back to var-cov estimated from RX
2: In vcov.merMod(object, correlation = correlation, sigm = sig) :
  variance-covariance matrix computed from finite-difference Hessian is
not positive definite or contains NA values: falling back to var-cov estimated from RX

The messages are always the same after center and scale the data scale(Chla_model[,2:15],center = TRUE, scale = TRUE) or even normalize normalize(Chla).
Here are the summarized data:
Chla_model <- read.csv(
    "D:/Article Sediment/ACP en langage R/Chla_model.csv", sep=";", 
    stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
str(Chla_model)

'data.frame':   45 obs. of  16 variables:
 $ season     : Factor w/ 3 levels "Dry","Flood",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Temp       : num  30 28.9 29.8 30 30.7 31.1 32.7 33.3 31 31.7 ...
 $ EC         : num  61 126 64 67 74 ...
 $ DO         : num  5.59 3.55 3.96 2.74 2.58 5.62 3.37 6.24 4.57 5.14 ...
 $ pH         : num  7.6 6.5 7.3 6.8 6.8 7.7 7 8 7.5 7 ...
 $ Sal        : num  0.0268 0.0579 0.0282 0.0297 0.0314 0.0302 0.0574 0.0345 0.0423 0.0975 ...
 $ TP         : num  0.15 0.43 0.09 0.16 0.15 0.09 0.17 0.05 0.65 1.59 ...
 $ PO43.      : num  0.08 0.09 0.04 0.04 0.02 0.04 0.02 0.04 0.09 0.09 ...
 $ NO3.       : num  1.4 0.95 0.34 0.17 0.23 0.21 0.25 0.8 1.07 1.15 ...
 $ TN         : num  2.43 1.84 2.39 0.74 2.41 0.37 0.69 1.31 1.96 1.85 ...
 $ NH4.       : num  0.06 0.05 0.08 0.03 0.08 0.05 0.1 0.07 0.05 0.04 ...
 $ NO2.       : num  0.011 0.005 0.019 0.015 0.018 0.013 0.02 0.02 0.012 0.014 ...
 $ Chla       : num  29.84 55.49 18.63 18.72 2.71 ...
 $ Discharge  : num  9.5 9.5 9.5 9.5 9.5 72.3 72.3 72.3 72.3 72.3 ...
 $ Pluviometry: num  115 115 115 115 115 ...
 $ river      : Factor w/ 3 levels "Bandama","Bia",..: 3 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 ...

I welcome any help you can give me.

Chla isn't count data, so why are you fitting a poisson-model?

@Lukas Lohse Can you suggest a method, if possible, with examples? I'm a beginner.
